# Using NIST constructions based on Keccak like cSHAKE128 for other sponges

Tags: mac, keccak, sponge, xof, kmac

NIST defines a lot of interesting applications of sponges in [FIPS 202](http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.202) and [NIST SP 800-185](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-185) like the XOF *cSHAKE128* or the MAC scheme *KMAC*.

All this schemes come with a security guarantee and are explicitly based on a sponge using *Keccak* as its permutation.

This leads me to two questions:

1. Do these constructions really rely on Keccak (apart from minor technical details like the padding length) or can they be adapted to different sponges without loosing security (assuming the alternative sponge function used is secure enough, of course)?
2. Are there any papers or standards published, which propose similar constructions which are not dependent on a single sponge instance?

Comment: No, the constructions don't inherently depend on the permutation chosen. You could easily replace Kecccak with a reduced-round version or with eg Gimli.

Comment: @SEJPM Maybe also mention that [Gimli cryptanalysis](https://www.shiftleft.org/papers/boromir/) shows that creating a good $f$ function is not an easy thing to do… even for professionals.

Comment: @e-sushi I do not intend to invent my own permutation function. I just want to research, how careful I have to be in using an established sponge.

Comment: Related: [Can we exchange the permutation of a sponge construction?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/38050/can-we-exchange-the-permutation-of-a-sponge-construction?rq=1)

Comment: @mat Always double check the work if you're able to specify an output length that is larger than the state size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we exchange the permutation of a sponge construction?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/38050/can-we-exchange-the-permutation-of-a-sponge-construction)

Comment: I don't think this is really a duplicate. This asks if another sponge can be swapped in, not another permutation. I don't think it's trivially answered by the other.

Comment: @otus What is the difference between swapping in another sponge and swapping in another permutation?  The only parameter a sponge has _besides_ the permutation is the rate/capacity.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage, a sponge function doesn't even necessarily have to use a permutation, does it?

Comment: @otus Technically the syntax of the sponge construction doesn't require it, and there are some theoretical results about uniform random function sponges _vs._ uniform random permutation sponges, _e.g._ in the [paper introducing sponges](https://keccak.team/files/SpongeFunctions.pdf), but I've never heard of anyone proposing to actually instantiate the construction with a non-permutation.  In any case, it seems to me that replacement of the permutation by a non-permutation would be in the scope of the linked question too, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/38050/49826.